Can short movie fragments be used as experimental stimuli?
Has anybody any experience with usage rights of movie fragments for research purposes? In case the movies are recent, are you aware of rules regarding usage? Unfortunately I am not aware of the regulations in place.
I am aware that in the case of static visual stimuli, using Creative Commons images is standard for experiments, but I have not been able to find out whether this applies to movie snippets as well? I would like to mention that I intend to use these movie snippets/fragments in order to trigger emotion in experimental settings.
Thank you!

Legal questions may be better for law.SE. You may also want to specify the location, as laws may differ between countries. I did help with an experiment that triggered emotions using sound bytes taken from a public domain library, so I suspect that researchers prefer to stay out of potential copyright infringement territory.
